# Is this kind of grouping supported for Silverlight 4 DataGrid?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

Is this kind of grouping possible for Silverlight DataGrids?

[image: Silverlight DataGrid Grouping]

The first three rows of the first column are combined into one block because their data are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the default Silverlight datagrid control does not support this kind of grouping, however you can achive a similar result using template columns:

First you should create a Class that would contain the grouped data, something like this:

```
MySourceClass
{
   string GroupColumn {get;set;}
   List<object> GroupedColumn1 {get;set;}
}
```

Then bind your DataGrid to a collection of `MySourceClass` (or whatever name you call it), and create a `TextColumn` for Column1, and a `TemplateColumn` for Column2 with a `ListBox` or similar, and bind the source of the `Listbox` to the `GroupedColumn` property.

You might have to thinker a bit with the styles, but i'm pretty sure you can acomplish a solid look with this aproach.

EDIT: 
Alternatively you could use the default DataGrid grouping, her's a good example for it:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134340/Grouping-Records-in-Silverlight-DataGrid-using-Pag

Comment: That's a bit of a hack with other complications. :-)  For example, I cannot just use my server data contract the way I like, and tabbed editing will be messed up, but it is probably the closest to a working solution.

Comment: I will not use this answer (see my previous comment), but I marked it as the answer because it is probably the closest solution to simulate the desired result.